# Is it possible to see python codes even after converted to .exe?

Tags: python

Is really possible to find or see codes of a .exe program written whit python?

If yes what should do to protect program?

Thanks

Comment: No, once it's compiled it's compiled. Like any executable, you can reverse engineer it but it being written in Python doesn't compromise it any further, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: So you are 100% sure it can't be reverse engineer?